# setDataSource() IO exception

Tags: java, android

I'm having a certain problem when playing an mp3 file specified by the user with MediaPlayer.

```
try {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), audio);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
            numberText.setText("IO EXCEPTION");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the problem is in mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), audio)

Here I get the specified mp3 from the user

```
setAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);


        }


        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    audioPath = intent.getData().getPath();
                    audio = Uri.parse(audioPath);
                }
            }
        }


    });
```

The error log shows this

```
setDataSource: SecurityException! uri=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1545
                                                                                  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{7b8354b 23595:com.example.m1tr0s0ul4s.thatawkwardcall/u0a137} (pid=23595, uid=10137) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3372)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4819)
                                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2527)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1486)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1092)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:932)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:859)
                                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:987)
                                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:961)
                                                                                      at com.example.m1tr0s0ul4s.thatawkwardcall.AcceptCall.onCreate(AcceptCall.java:55)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
10-20 17:31:13.041 23595-23595/com.example.m1tr0s0ul4s.thatawkwardcall 
E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player
```

I have literally no idea what is going on :/ please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are already requesting for Runtime Permissions try this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
   intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("*/*");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} else {
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   intent.setType("*/*");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

If you're not then you must check for Runtime Permissions in Marshmallow and above.
Add this code to your Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Now in your onClick of setAudio you need to check if the user has given you permissions to access the storage of the device

```
setAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 11);

        }  else {
              //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                      intent = new Intent();
                      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                      intent.setType("*/*");
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                 } else {
                      intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                      intent.setType("*/*");
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                 }
       }
}
```

When you request permission the user action is returned in **onRequestPermissionResult(..)**. Here's how you could handle the user action.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
   super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
   if (requestCode == 11) {
       if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           //The External Storage READ Permission is granted to you... Continue your left job...
                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                      intent = new Intent();
                      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                      intent.setType("*/*");
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                 } else {
                      intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                      intent.setType("*/*");
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                 }
       } else{
           //permission denied
       }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the first section of code in my answer ?. Its the next thing you should try if you've permissions placed properly.

Comment: Well that fixed it. Thanks. But I already had the permission line in my manifest so I don't get where the problem was

Comment: Just adding to manifest won't help it. You need to either ask for permissions in real time or make the user go to Settings and enable the permission. Also the first section of code wasn't related to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
                audioPath = intent.getData().getPath();
                audio = Uri.parse(audioPath);
```

`intent.getData()` already returns an `Uri` object, so you're potentially throwing away data required to read the specific file like the scheme, host or query properties.

Comment: So I can just do audio = intent.getData(); ??